# How to loop over the values of a field during MongoDB project?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, projection

**Question:**

What I want is to loop over on the values of a field during the Mongo [**project**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/),

**For Example:**
Here is a small sample of my data

```
{
"_id": ObjectId(1),
"field1": {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2"
} 
},
{
"_id": ObjectId(1),
"field1": {
   "key1":"value1",
   "key2":"value2",
   "key3":"value3"
}
} 
}
```

And my query is something like this:

```
MyDocument._get_collection().aggregate([
  # some match statement
  
  "$project": { 
     'customized_data': {
        '$ifNull': ['$field1.key1', "default_value"]
     }
  }
])
```

So my query is suitable just for one key. (key1 from field1).
So how can I loop over `"field1"` values `("key1":"value1", "key2":"value2", "key3": "value3")`and in order to a specific condition change output?

**NOTE:**
I'm using the latest version of `MongoDB4.2` so far

Comment: You can use the aggregation [$objectToArray](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/index.html) operator - this returns a array. Then you can loop over the array using one of the aggregation array operators (like $map).

Comment: @prasad_ You know what makes your suggestion impossible, I want to compare each value separately. for example ```value1 greater than 1 and value2 greater than 2 and so on```

Comment: And BTW thanks for your comment